# Serverless custom plugin - compiledCloudFormationTemplate

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I’m creating a custom plugin to change the resources with type AWS::Lambda::Alias. I’m using serverless.service.provider.compiledCloudFormationTemplate.Resources to get all the alias resources and amend them, however when I log all the types, it seems the alias are not resources cause they are not listed … any idea why?

Project reference: https://github.com/EstefaniaExamples/NurseryServerlessApp/blob/d60c568f9ac87ddb2fc3da01cbbd9542d5b87125/ci/plugins/technical-config.js#L49

Thanks so much in advance